# Storing Google's Reverse Geocoded values

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

So, my app involves a lot of reverse geocoding. Now, Google permits only 2500 requests/day.
I was wondering if I could store the reverse geocoded values in my database, so for future requests for approximately the same latitude/longitude pair, I can query my database instead of sending a request to the Google Maps API. Is it illegal to do so ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of service (legal issues) not coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By my reading of the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/terms.html), you **might** be able to (IANAL)...

> 10. **License Restrictions.** Except as expressly permitted under the Terms, or unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), Google's licenses above are subject to your adherence to all of the restrictions below. Except as explicitly permitted in Section 7 or the Maps APIs Documentation, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):
>
> <snip>
>
> 10.3 pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;

Comment: Thanks Jon. I think Google could've been clearer on this clause.

Comment: Despite a map is an intellectual property, a place name and its coordinates cannot be considered as an "intellectual property". So I guess you should be entitled to do that even if this is not encouraged by Google for obvious reasons.